# SQL count for the union of two different count

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have two different queries first one will give me the number of users with having outgoing calls per each day and the second one will give me the number of users with having incoming calls per each day. I want an unioin of these two queries. I mean I want the number of users with having incoming or outgoing calls per each day. What would be the correct query for such results?

```
1) select call_date, count(*) 
from 
(select distinct anum,call_date 
from  CDR 
where anum in (select msisdn from degree_cmp_week1)
)
group by call_date 
order by call_date;

2) select call_date, count(*) 
from 
(select distinct bnum,call_date 
from  CDR 
where bnum in (select msisdn from degree_cmp_week1)
)
group by call_date 
order by call_date;
```

FYI CDR is a table of call details record. It include the anum (source of call), bnum (destination of call) and the date of call. I am looking for calculating the number of persons that have any kind of activities (call somebody or somebody call him/her) per each day. The first query will give me the number of persons as a source of calls and the second one will give me the number of persons as destination of calls. Suppose the first query give me n(A) and the second query give me n(B). I am looking for n(A Union B). As you know n(A U B)=n(A)+n(B)- n(A intersection B). So finding n(A intersection B) will help me too.

P.S: I use oracle 11 so please consider that.

Comment: Please add a little bit more information. What is the table structure of CDR? What is some data that might be in the table? What are the expected results of the query based on that data?

Comment: Please take a look at my question again. I added some information.

Comment: One more question, are you just looking for the total number of incoming and outgoing calls? What I mean is that if you had one query that returns the total number, would that be okay or do you need the two numbers separately?

Comment: One query for total number would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Simply ask in the query for in - and outgoing calls:

```
select call_date, count(num) 
from 
 (select distinct anum as num, call_date 
  from  CDR 
  where anum in (select msisdn from degree_cmp_week1)
  )
  union 
  (select distinct bnum as num ,call_date 
  from CDR
  where bnum in (select msisdn from degree_cmp_week1)
  )
group by call_date 
order by call_date;
```

Comment: Your query is not what I want. You did not consider the situation where bnum,call_date is distinct.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I've updated the query but am not sure whether it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could give you both in a single query:

```
with ids as (
  select distinct msisdn
  from degree_cmp_week1
), calls as (
  select
    call_date,
    nvl2 (i1.msisdn, 1, 0) as a_count,
    nvl2 (i2.msisdn, 1, 0) as b_count
  from
    CDR,
    ids i1,
    ids i2
  where
    CDR.anum = i1.msisdn (+) and
    CDR.bnum = i2.msisdn (+)
)
select
  call_date, sum (a_count) as a_count,
  sum (b_count) as b_count
from calls
group by call_date
order by call_date
```

Comment: I dont know what your mentioned query do, but I test that and it is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe include some sample input and expected output?

Comment: I added more information about my query and CDR table.